# Drop Time stamp while pulling data from oracle table to java

Tags: java, oracle

Currently I am getting date from oracle table as string which is giving me date as well as timesstamp. Is there a way I can drop timestamp and just get the date from table. Currently in my java code Date is declare as string which pulls date and timestamp.Thank you

```
setDate(rset.getString(1));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`ResultSet#getDate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28int%29) will return just the date component, as a [`java.sql.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) (which has hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds set to zero). You can turn that `Date` object into a string afterwards.

I would, however, recommend storing date information as a `Date`, not as a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful of using the term "timestamp". Timestamp is a datatype in Oracle.

If you're asking how do you eliminate the 'time' portion of the date. You can use the TRUNC() function in Oracle. Or you could NOT use a string on the Java side, use a date instead and set the format to not show the time portion.

Comment: Actually, `TIMESTAMP` is a standard term, one of [the data types defined by the SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types).

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) supports [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr221/index.html) or later, it may be able to handle the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types which supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar and java.sql types. Call the `setObject` method on a `PreparedStatement` and `getObject` on the `ResultSet`.

Date-only types will appear in Java as `java.time.LocalDate`. Time-of-day-only types will appear in Java as `java.time.LocalTime`. A timestamp (a date-time) will appear as an `java.time.Instant`.

If your driver does not yet offer this support, fall back to using the `java.sql` types as shown in the [correct Answer by Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7598634/642706). Then immediately convert to java.time types. Perform your business logic in java.time types; use java.sql types only for data-exchange with database. Look to new methods added on the old classes for convenient conversions.

```
LocalDate ld = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate() ;
LocalTime lt = myJavaSqlTime.toLocalTime() ;
Instant instant = myJavaSqlTimestamp.toInstant() ;
```

Going the other direction, look at the `valueOf` or `from` methods.